# Type mismatches with Mediaplayer setup

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I am trying to follow the tutorial: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion but with just a quick copy and paste I am immediately getting the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to MediaPlayer" for the following lines:

```
 MediaPlayer mp = players.get(music);
```

additional information:

```
private static HashMap players = new HashMap();
```

and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to MediaPlayer" for:

```
 for (MediaPlayer p : mps) {
```

additional information:

```
Collection mps = players.values();
```

Any ideas why and how to solve this? PS I am a novice programmer so please explain all details where necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem with the line :

```
private static HashMap players = new HashMap();
```

you have to write

```
private static HashMap<Int,MediaPlayer> players = new HashMap();
```

and on each "Collection mps" line you have a cast it to (MediaPlayer)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the hashmap to a sparsearray:

this line:

```
private static HashMap players = new HashMap();
```

to this:

```
private static SparseArray<MediaPlayer> players = new SparseArray<MediaPlayer>();
```

Then in each of the Collection mps occurrences I used:

```
for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
{
   if(players.get(i).isPlaying())
      players.get(i).pause();
}
```

or something along those lines